# Jackson Deserializer throws JsonParseException with Invalid UTF-8 middle byte while deserializer String with accents

Tags: java, xml, rest, jackson

HTTP request body example

```
<Name>Cátia</Name>
```

HTTP response body example

```
<Name>C�tia</Name>
```

Here is the request class

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Root")
public class Request {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "Id")
    private String id;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "Name")
    private String name;
}
```

Here is HTTP request

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml;charset=UTF-8");

HttpEntity<> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, httpHeaders);

responseEntity = restTemplate
    .exchange("URL", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Response.class);
```

Here is Response class

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ResponseDeserializer.class)
public class Response {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "NAME")
    public String name;
}
```

Here is ResponseDeserializer class

```
public class ResponseDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Response> {
    @Override
    public Response deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

        ObjectCodec objectCodec = p.getCodec();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectCodec.readTree(p);

        return JsonUtils.getObjectMapper().readValue(JsonUtils.getObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonNode),
            Response.class);
    }
}
```

Here is the exception

> JsonNode jsonNode = objectCodec.readTree(p);
>
> readTree method threw 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException'
> exception. Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x74 (at char #2480, byte #1371)

Comment: Obviously there is a character encoding problem. Seems the response is not encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @Henry
Is there any workaround? The response contain UTF-8 in the encoding declaration.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
`<Name>C�tia</Name>`

Comment: Is there an specified in the response HTTP header?

Comment: Just recognized, the character 0x74 is a 't' This would indicate that the server is not sending UTF-8 although it claims to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding isUTF8Support=true as a HTTP URL parameter.